# queryLoader2 onProgress doesn't work (no error)

Tags: jquery

I'm using [queryLoader2](https://github.com/Gaya/queryloader2) to preload a page. It works fine except that I can't get the percentage variable.

In the documentation it says:

> onProgress  ***function*** this function is called when an image is loaded.
>   Get parameters *percentage*, *imagesLoaded*, *totalImages*. Default: *none*

Here's my code:

```js
$("body").queryLoader2({
 percentage: true,
 onProgress: function(percentage, done, total){
  console.log(percentage, done, total);
  $("body").prepend(percentage);
 }
});
```

```css
img{
width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/jquery@3.1.0,jquery.queryloader2@2.3"></script>
  
<div class="delayer">
    <img src="http://deelay.me/200/http://deelay.me/img/1000ms.gif" alt="">
    <img src="http://deelay.me/500/http://deelay.me/img/1000ms.gif" alt="">
    <img src="http://deelay.me/1200/http://deelay.me/img/1000ms.gif" alt="">
    <img src="http://deelay.me/1500/http://deelay.me/img/1000ms.gif" alt="">
    <img src="http://deelay.me/1800/http://deelay.me/img/1000ms.gif" alt="">
    <img src="http://deelay.me/2200/http://deelay.me/img/1000ms.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

I'm clueless as to what it may be. Bug?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using an older version (2.3) instead of the latest 3.2.2.

Idiot :) Downloaded the latest version from gitHub instead of using CDN and works great.